# Three Address code for an arithmetic operation containing only integers?

Tags: yacc, lex, intermediate-code

I am trying to convert a miniC program (limited features) into a 3AC using lex and yacc. I read a bit about it on google but all the examples given always have some variable in their operations. What If in the source code theres something like this

```
x = 2+3+4;
```

Will the 3AC for this would look like?

```
t0 = 2+3;
t1 = t0+4;
x = t1;
```

Or should this be optimized to?

```
 x = 9;
```

For the first implementation I think its fairly easy. But if second is the way to go, how would I implement that? How do compilers handle this situation? Do they generate the **second** 3AC right away? Or do they start with the **first** 3AC and then have multiple passes for optimizations?

(I am not looking to implement a multiple pass 3AC generator)

Comment: Compilers usually create an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and do transformations on it before generating the final result. As for which output you prefer, I'm not able to tell.

Comment: What do you mean which output? Are you talking about the 3AC?